# How to prevent color fiter change of one ImageView, when changing other?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-glide

If I set color filter on `ivOld`, other one `ivNew` will change filter too. How to prevent it?

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    Photo photo = (Photo) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
    ImageView ivOld = (ImageView) ((LinearLayout) view).getChildAt(0);

    if (!photo.isSelected()) {
        mPhotos.get(i).setSelected(true); // установить флажек глобальном массиве
        ivOld.add(photo); // добавить фото в массив выбранных

        ivOld.setEnabled(false); // отклчаем вызможность выбирать
        ivOld.getDrawable().setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.DKGRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY)); // налагаем фильтр

        //создание нового фото в выбранных
        ImageView ivNew = getImageView(this);
        Glide.with(this).load(photo.getPhotoPath()).centerCrop().into(ivNew);

        ivNew.clearColorFilter();
        //ivNew.getDrawable().clearColorFilter();
        ivNew.setTag(new PhotosAdapter.ViewHolder(photo, ivSelecting));
        ivNew.setOnClickListener(this);

        mLinearLayout.addView(ivNew);
    }
}

private ImageView getImageView(Context context) {
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(context);
        iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        iv.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(mPicWidth, mPicWidth));
        return iv;
    }
```

Comment: What the method getImageView do? Can you show us how you initialize ivOld? It seems that ivOld and ivNew are referencing to same object...

Comment: @Neonamu ImageViews are initialized by the same image path using Glide

Comment: @Neonamu added code